# excel vba Assign cell value to variable from Autofilter result

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get the values from column N2 and M2, after using autofilter, the assignation only gives me values present in the entire sheet not in the autofilter range.

```
Sub mainSub()
Dim fRngb as Range

For Each key In fCatId.Keys
With wshcore
    llastrow = wshcore.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:N" & llastrow).AutoFilter
    .Range("A1:N" & llastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=fCatId(key)
    min = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Range("H:H"))
    max = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(4, Range("H:H"))

    'This does not work. it gives the first 13,2 value not the filtered one.
     Set fRngb = wshcore.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     'MsgBox fRngb.Cells(13, 2)
     'I've also tried this:
    'Range("K2:K2").CurrentRegion.Value(2)

     Debug.Print fRngb.Cells(13, 2) & " -  " & Range("K2:K2").CurrentRegion.Value(2)
End With
Next key
End Sub
```

any suggestions?

Comment: After the filter, you can copy the column ranges (for example `.Range("N2:M" & llastrow).Copy` and paste it somewhere. That will copy just the visible cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarification:

- use `.Areas()` property of `Range` object to return a collection of all contiguous ranges its is made of
- get its first "area" with index 1 :`.Areas(1)`
- get its first cell resizing it down to one row: `.Areas(1).Resize(1)`

here follows full code:

```
Sub mainSub()
    Dim fRngb As range

    With wshcore
        With .range("A1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            For Each Key In fCatId.Keys
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=fCatId(Key)
                Min = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, .Columns("H")) 
                Max = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(4, .Columns("H")) 
                Set fRngb = .Columns("N").Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| get all column "N" (relative to considered range) filtered values excluded header row
                MsgBox fRngb.Areas(1).Resize(1).Address '<--| get its first cell
                .AutoFilter
            Next Key
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I guess fCatId is some `Public` variable of `Dictionary` type... Otherwise you must pass it to `mainSub` as a parameter

Comment: min and max are to get the the min/max values from that column, within the filtered range. fcatId is a dict I have to control other info. I've tested the code it gives a "runtime error 5" Invalid procedure call or argument here: "With  .Range("A1:N" & .Cells("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)"

Comment: Yeah, it must be "With .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row". See edited code

Comment: I think we're almost there, it now returns the header name, how to get it return the first (second row in the filter) row with data? thank you. btw I'm using Msgbox fRngb.Value as I need the value in the cell which is a string. I've tried with fRngb.Address(RowAbsolute:=False) but it gives me the range not the value.